# MongoDB Multiple Near Queries

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I am trying to design a query that I can pass to MongoDB that would effectively get all the zipcodes in a specified radius for multiple zipcodes.

For example, I would pass it a list of zipcodes (`["10001", "97201", "37208"]`) and a radius of 20km. The response would be the list of all zipcodes that fall within that radius.

Here is an example of a document in my collection, where there is a 2dsphere index on `loc`.

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b035a9f5ec1e38a0e668be"), 
    "zipcode" : "10001", 
    "city" : "New York", 
    "state_full" : "New York", 
    "state" : "NY", 
    "county" : "New York", 
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point", 
        "coordinates" : [
            -73.9967, 
            40.7484
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the best solution is, or even this would be possible in one query/map-reduce. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Near to what? Within the radius of "each" of the zipcodes provided in the list? Or within the "intersection of the radius" from "all" the zipcodes provided? Likely the former. I presume that is does not matter what order the "returned list" of zipcodes is actually in?

Comment: @NeilLunn Right, so it would effectively iterate through the provided list and give me the set of zipcodes and each zipcode that would fall in the radius. It would look like `(10001 with all zips in 10 mi) & (97201 with all zips in 10 mi) & (37208 with all zips in 10 mi)`. The parentheses in this example are nothing more than just groupings to illustrate my end goal. For my current application, the order of the zipcodes doesn't matter.